# sanitization to perform on user comments?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter

When displaying user comments, what type of sanitation should be performed?

I want to allow users to display links, use styling like bold and italics, but obviously prevent injection of javascript and other scripting tags.

using htmlspecialchars() would strip all <> characters, so it would prevent users from styling their comments unless some form of codes like BBCodes are used.

1. would using strip_tags() be a better option?
2. is there any security flaw I am missing that can be prevented with more sanitation?

(on a side note, does frameworks such as codeigniter already provide a function of this nature?)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `strip_tags` is essentially a blacklist approach; it removes things that are deemed inappropriate. The suggested approach (allow X, Y and Z) is whitelisting, which is generally more secure.

Comment: @MSalters actually strip_tags() is a whitelist approach. echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>'); would only allow <p> and <a> tags.

Comment: ... plus all their attributes, including possibly JavaScript. (I've made it a comment because, as your example shows, there's a grey area between whitelisting and blacklisting.)

Comment: You are looking for HTMLPurifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strip_tags is not quite safe, there is good article about this http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/nj5t0/what_everyone_should_know_about_strip_tags/

Comment: yes. after some research, i realize that strip_tags() is not a full solution due to possible javascript inject on events.

Comment: That article is mostly misattributions. Even though the third point is worth repeating. It's verbatim in the manual however.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using something like Markdown for user-supplied input. That way they can style their text and you can control what styling they can use.